# Multiple Loader Call Back Android

Tags: android, kotlin, loader

I have tried this code:

```
loaderManager.initLoader(99, null, object : LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<String> {
            override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle): Loader<String>? {
                val baseUri = Uri.parse("xxxxxx") //this is a private web, so i can't show it to you
                val uriBuilder = baseUri.buildUpon()
                Log.i("URI BUILDER:", uriBuilder.toString())
                return InputProductLoader(applicationContext, uriBuilder.toString(), product)
            }

            override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<String>?, data: String?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<String>?) {
                TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        })
```

I would like to have 2 loader in an activity and each loader will have call back like that (they have different return type each other), but the problem is it doesn't work. my app sudenly force close if i implement that code. (this time i only make a single loader first)

these are the log

```
08-31 15:52:05.795 2914-2914/id.devcamp.expiredat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: id.devcamp.expiredat, PID: 2914
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter args
    at id.devcamp.expiredat.InputProductActivity$onCreate$3$1.onCreateLoader(InputProductActivity.kt)
    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:546)
    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:555)
    at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:609)
    at id.devcamp.expiredat.InputProductActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(InputProductActivity.kt:68)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

i have try to make my activity implement LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks but the problem is i can't convert my String(one of the result from loader) to Obejcts.

so how to make multiple loader in a sigle activity

Comment: "my app is suddenly force close" is not helpful, post exception stack trace.

Comment: I have added the stack trace, sir, thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have fallen for incorrect Java interop - for some reason Kotlin IDE generated override methods with incompatible signature.

1. Consider using `supportLoaderManager` instead - `loaderManager` got deprecated but it has been inconsistent for some versions already.
2. Incorrect override signature (nullable paremeter specified as non-nullable):

`override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle): Loader<String>?` crashes because `args` can be null, and it should never return a null so change it to:
`override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<String>`.

`onLoadFinished` and `onLoaderReset` will never provide `null` loader, so you can remove nullability check from the `Loader<String>?` there.